# Excel formula to make cell read-only

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula to make an Excel cell read-only based on criteria.
For example - if A2 is empty, make B2 and C2 read-only.

I haven't been able to find any examples of this.  Can anyone help out?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with only a formula. You will most likely need VB to handle this.

Comment: Use ***Data Validation***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with a formula. Where would you want to put it? Not in A2 (here's the original data or empty), not in B2 or C2, here's where you might want to put new data.

You may put a warning symbol in a different cell, e.g. D2. Or, as suggested, you might want to use Data Validation on B2 and C2 to prevent them from receiving new input, if A2 is empty: Data Validation -> Custom -> Formula =NOT(ISEMPTY(A2)) and uncheck the "Igonre empty cells" option.

Anyway, this does not prevent you from eratsing B2 and C2 if A2 is empty. So for perfection, a VBA solution would be necessary.